# length of the focal chord

Tags: conic-sections

**Paragraph:**

$PQ$ is a focal chord of the
parabola: $y^2=4ax.$

The tangents to the parabola at
the points $P$ and $Q$ meet at point $R$ which lies on the line $y=2x + a.$

**Question:**

Find the length of the chord $PQ.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geometrical proof for length of chord passing through vertex of parabola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098272/geometrical-proof-for-length-of-chord-passing-through-vertex-of-parabola)

Answer (score 2):

Find the point R. It comes out to be
(-a,-a)

And then we take the points P and Q to
be represented parametrically by c and d.
Thus we have:
c + d = -1 ...(1)
If we take the points P and Q to be
the parametric points c and d on the parabola then we have the length
of the chord to be:
Length = PS + QS
            =  a + a + ac<sup>2</sup>
+ ad<sup>2</sup>
            =  2a + a(c<sup>2</sup>+d<sup>2</sup>)
We need the value of (c<sup>2</sup> +
d<sup>2</sup>)
Since:
cd = -1
 c + d = -1 (from (1))
(c + d)<sup>2</sup> = c<sup>2</sup> +
d<sup>2</sup> + 2cd
1 = c<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>2</sup> -2
c<sup>2</sup> + d<sup>2</sup> = 3
=> Thus length = 5a.

Comment: Proof of first statement:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475666/prove-that-in-a-parabola-the-tangent-at-one-end-of-a-focal-chord-is-parallel-to?rq=1