# Relation between end point of focal chord of parabola

Tags: conic-sections

Consider a parabola $y^2 = 4ax$ , parameterize it as $x=at^2$ and $y=2at$, then it is found that if we have a line segment passing through focus, with each points having value of $t$ as $t_1$ and $t_2$ for the parameterization, then it must be that:

$$ t_1 \cdot t_2 = -1$$

Hope for hints.

Comment: Write the equation for chord passing through points $t_1,t_2$ and let it pass through $(a,0)$. Also, your coordinates are swapped. Points should be $(at^2,2at)$.

Comment: I got $ \frac{1}{t_1} + \frac{1}{t_2}=2$

Comment: You must have made some error. I get $t_1t_2=-1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chord passing through $(at_1^2,2at_1)$ and $(at_2^2,2at_2)$ is
$$y-2at_2=\frac{2at_1-2at_2}{at_1^2-at_2^2}(x-at_2^2)$$
$$y-2at_2=\frac{2}{t_1+t_2}(x-at_2^2)$$

It should pass through focus $(a,0)$
$$\Rightarrow -at_2=\frac{1}{t_1+t_2}\,a(1-t_2^2)$$
$$\Rightarrow t_1t_2=-1$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let the parameters be $p,q$. So the eq of the line is $(y-2ap)(ap^2-aq^2)=(x-ap^2)(2ap-2aq)$. What point does this pass through so that it is a focal chord?

Comment: what parameterization have you used?

Answer (score 0):

Working back from geometry makes everything supremely trivial, following [blue's post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475666/prove-that-in-a-parabola-the-tangent-at-one-end-of-a-focal-chord-is-parallel-to/475949#comment8754357_475949), it must be that at the tangent vectors at end point of focal chord is perpendicular.

Our curve is given as $\gamma(y) = ( \frac{y^2}{4a},y)$, the tangent vector is given as: $\tau(y) = (\frac{y}{2a},1)$, let the two points we want be at height $(y_1,y_2)$, then due to tangents at end point being perpendicular:

$$ \tau(y_1) \cdot \tau(y_2)=0$$

Expanding everything out:
$$ y_1 y_2 = -4a$$

Now plugging in the parameterization, we find the parametric version of the result.